# Hasura Timeout, Queries with Inconsistent speed Issues

Tags: database, postgresql, graphql, hasura

I have a table with 2 millions of data in it, lets say I search for user email Id(using _ilike), it takes more than 15 to 20 seconds (or sometime I get Timeout error) to respond with out indexing. With indexing I get within a second(still there are times where it takes 15 to 20s, let say 2 out of 10 times I have this delay).

Now the question following are the question I have,

1. There is timeout most of the time when we search for mail id which is not present in the table, why is that? Whether this is expected behavior?
2. How much space/configuration of the DB does Hasura is expected to have for approximate 2 millions data?
3. Whether btree indexing is better for _ilike searchs or gin indexing is the better solution?
4. Any more suggestions to improve the performance of the query other than indexing?
5. Even the basic query to get the count of the rows is pretty slow, is there a way to improve?

> ```
> `userTable_aggregate {
>             aggregate {
>               count    
>             }    
>           }`
> ```

Note: Every one hour data is getting added to the userTable(lets 100 approximate).
Thank you for taking time to answer my questions

Comment: Are you aware about "Analyze" in Hasura UI? What it displays?

Comment: Yes, the analyze tool shows high cost. It shows that index has been added but still the query is quite slow.

Comment: Then paste execution plan to get recommendation what to do next